# How to copy pagefile.sys in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I need to copy Windows 7's pagefile.sys (and other files that are always in-use/open) to another location. Is there any free tool that can do this ? I'm thinking of finding a way to access Volume Shadow and transfer it this way or some Direct Disk Access Mode. Don't ask me for the reason I want to do that, just provide a solution if you have one. The files must be copied without terminating the processes that keep them open.
Thank you in advance.
Note that things like hobocopy return 'used by another process error'.

Answer (score 1):

I found a free alternate tool that can do what I need (Shadow Explorer). 
It can be downloaded from their official site shadowexplorer.com. 
The application auto-mounts supported volumes and then any file operations can be performed from there.
I was able to transfer both pagefile.sys and complete folders to a standard drive location.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/104/405927/30/660/threaded

*Extract*

> I've been successful pulling the pagefile.sys from a live
>   system using Disk Explorer from http://www.runtime.org (Won't work with the
>   demo version)
>
> - File->Drive (open the drive letter you want to copy from)
> - Goto->Root directory
> - Click on the pagefile's MFT#
> - Tools->Recover file

Alternatively - http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2011/10/how-to-acquire-locked-files-from.html

Comment: I know Disk Explorer but it's not free (and it wouldn't be time-efficient either to extract dozens of files). Robocopy does not support individual file copy and and can't use subst for a single root file.

Comment: I found a free alternate tool that can do what I need (Shadow Explorer). This question can e closed.

Comment: then post that as an answer, so others can find it